# How to: Ruby Range that doesn't include the first value

Tags: ruby

With Ranges in Ruby you can do `0..5` to include all numbers between and including 0 and 5. You can also do `0...5` to include the same numbers except 5 is not included.

```
(1..5) === 5
=> true
(1...5) === 5
=> false
(1...5) === 4.999999
=> true
```

Is there a way to exclude the first number instead of the last to get a result like this?

```
(1...5) === 1
=> false
(1...5) === 1.00000001
=> true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in support for such a range. You might want to roll your own `Range`-like class if this behavior is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to understand what I needed (not just 2...5). Too bad there's no built-in support. I think that it will just be easier to test if the number > 1 && number <= 5 than to create my own class.I imagine if I did want to create my own class, I could internally use a Range object, but just provide slightly different implementation of the ===, include?, member?, etc methods.

Comment: You could use a Range object internally with all of the values negated. For example, the internal range would be (-5...-1). That would include -5, but exclude -1. Of course, this will only work for ranges whose values have negations.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively with a Range. You can mess with its mind but you're better off using an incremented first value. This is ugly but:

```
[(1..5).to_s].map{ |s| a,b=s.split('..').map{|i| i.to_i}; (1+a .. b) } #=> [2..5]
```

or

```
Range.new(*[(1..5).to_s].map{ |s| a,b=s.split('..').map{|i| i.to_i}; [1+a,b] }.flatten) #=> 2..5
```

or

```
irb(main):004:0> asdf = (1..5)
=> 1..5
irb(main):005:0> Range.new(asdf.min.succ, asdf.max)
=> 2..5
```

None seem overly elegant.

Comment: They also don't match requirements. `(2..5)` doesn't include `1.001`, which I'm betting the OP actually needs for his script, or else he wouldn't have asked :/

Answer (score 0):

Besides just sending `first_arg.succ` instead of `first_arg`? No, there is no special support for this.

Comment: Except that `(2..5)` doesn't actually meet the requirements :/

Comment: The requirements aren't based on a good understanding of how Range works. When that happens we usually fall back to learning how to work within the limitations of the language or the object, backing up a few steps and taking a different run at it. Changing the language or object's behavior to meet the specs can lead to madness, or maybe burning off the atmosphere or opening a door into another dimension where [he who shall not be named](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu) can return and rain misery on us all... lo, he comes....

Answer (score -1):

You could monkey patch Range to add a method to behave the way you want. Ex:

```
class Range
    def exclusive()
        Range.new(self.first+1, self.last-1)
    end
end

(1..5).exclusive === 5
==>false
(1..5) === 5
==>true
```

Beware of monkeypatching though, as it changes the functionality of existing classes. There is probably a better way to do it in this case, but given the question, this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: `(1..5).exclusive` just returns `(2..4)`, which does not match the requirement of including `1.0001` :/